# What are some gdb commands that I can use to improve my debugging skills?

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode4, gdb

What are the available commands for gdb in Xcode 4 which I can use to debug my app?

(Although a relatively seasoned developer, I'm looking to expand my skills with this question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start from here http://darkdust.net/files/GDB%20Cheat%20Sheet.pdf, come is very handy.

Points worth mentioning

- You can attach gdb to an already running process, there by start
  debugging
- Enter on gdb command line will execute last instruction, comes in
  very handy
- You can do some amount of scripting with GDB, use -x falg to point to
  your script suppose you want to connect to a target over ip (remote
  debugging), and you dont want to remember its ip / kepp entering it
  every time. Starting from gdb 7.1 Python scripts are also supported
  so much more powerful now

  echo "target remote 192.168.XX.XX:1234" > gscript
  gdb -x gscript application

Ok some niche stuffs -

```
(gdb)start
(gdb)layout split               // list the assembly and c
(gdb)ni                         // exec next instruction in assembly
(gdb)print $pc                  // prints the contents of register PC(use $)
```

you can try doing some unit testing on the go

```
(gdb)start
(gdb)call factorial(5)
```

Suppose you dont want to disturb the the application timing (reatime behaviour) but still want to view some variable updates, you can try following

```
(gdb)start
(gdb)break <func>:<line>
(gdb)commands 1                  // '1' is the break number
> silent
> printf "var1 = %d\t var2 =%d\n",var1,var2
> continue
> end
```

data break points, conditional breakpoints can be very useful when debugging memory corruptions

```
(gdb)start
(gdb)watch var
(gdb)watch 0x80001212
```

debugging threads

```
(gdb)info threads
(gdb)thread 2                      // switch to thread '2'
```